# How can i solve Firefox refresh problem in JSF

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.3

I'm using primefaces 7.0.

I have following control

```
<p:inputText value="#{editBean.name}">
```

When I change the content without submit and press F5 it should be filled again with the initial value.

In Firefox I have the problem. It still shows the edited value after F5, even though the bean is running through the *init* setting.

I already tried to set:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.autoCompleteOffOnViewState</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

without any success.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: @BalusC: hmmm no full privileges on jsf-2.3 or PrimeFaces to close directly? ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje: PrimeFaces wasn't there at the moment. As to [jsf-2.3], nope, no dupehammer there (yet), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267996/version-tags-reloaded

Comment: thx for referencing to the answer!